MacOS XCode Catch22
I have a iMac (Retina 4K, 21.5-inch, 2017) which was running Ventura 13.5.1
I replaced with a Mac mini Apple M2 in Feb 2023 and the iMac is now only used occasionally (it is much slower and occasionally crashed) but I was using to restore iPhone backups.
At the time it suggested updating to 13.6.6
All seemed OK but the XCode icon was obscured and it informed me I needed to update to the latest version.
When I tried to do this it refused and said it could only be installed on 14.0 or later!
Why did Apple install a version that won't run and can I fix this?
(I am still running Ventura 13.5.1 on my Mac mini because 14 didn't seem to offer any advantages so won't be upgrading until I can tackle updating some of my old code).

This has come up before, I closed it as a duplicate of one previous question. You can find others by searching the site for „download Xcode“.
